# Why function 'constexpr' specifier should match?

Tags: c++

Why `constexpr` specifier on function declaration should match with definition if it makes sense only on definitions, i.e. function with only declaration visible in TU can not be constexpr

Comment: Are you asking why a definition and a declaration need to look the same? For the same reason that `int foo(int)` can't be the forward declaration for `void bar(std::string, float)`. A declaration *declares* a function, so it has to specify what that function looks like.

Comment: Since `constexpr` also implies inline, those functions also have to be defined in each TU where they are used. If you leave it off it would imply global visibility on functions and that would conflict.

Comment: @doug I just tested it on msvc. Calling constexpr marked fun with only declaration available in TU. It links successfully

Comment: Interesting. They are required to have the same definition in each TU. I wouldn't expect it to produce a compile time const though with just a declaration.

Comment: @doug if used in constexpr context it obviously fails to compile. If used in regular context it just emits function call

Comment: @SilvioMayolo arguments in your example are part of function signature, so it's not a good example. I can declare function with `void f(int name);` and define as `void f(int another_name) {}`. They don't look same

Comment: "if used in constexpr context it obviously fails to compile." sure. I wonder if the same, that it would link, would apply to an inline declaration w/o definition in the TU. I'm not sure it would be a legal construct. Always viewed inline and constexpr as requiring definition in each TU.

Comment: @doug it was probably bug in msvc with LTCG (LTO). I updated compiler and now there is link error. btw `constexpr` implies `const` which implies internal (`static`) linkage, `inline` is urelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was bug in my compiler implementation.
`constexpr` at namespace scope has internal linkage by default, so

> function with only declaration visible in TU

produces link error.

Answer (score 1):

Since the standard requires any compatible implementations obey that

> [dcl.constexpr] p1
>
> > If any declaration of a function or function template has a constexpr or consteval specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the same specifier.

This means it does not only require the `constexpr` specifier should appear in each declaration of the function in one TU but also that in every TU. If there is no otherwise specification, a declaration can also be a definition.

Comment: Because the standard says so. It's a trivial answer. I'm asking for reasoning why LWG decided it should match. The only reason that I can think of is to fail slightly earlier when non-constexpr forward declared function is used in constexpr context.